# How to display list of results

Tags: posts, list

I need to display a list of results which will include a name, time, etc. They will be in this format: [results](http://paponz.org/eventresults/2011McLeans.txt). I have looked at using tables, but short of writing a script to parse the text file, it wouldn't work. I think the best option is to make them appear in a monospaced font but I cannot find a way to do this that would not require code written on each post.

Cheers, Will.

Comment: im assuming that long red, medium red are considered individual posts? could you elaborate more on where your grabbing these results from?

Comment: I would reconsider and use a table, it's tabular data.

Comment: The whole thing should be one post, it will be grabbed from a txt file, as the other output formats are not 100% computer readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to import textual content and preserve its formatting, as opposed to parsing it into HTML?

I suppose the `<pre></pre>` tags are meant for exactly this. However I would consider spending osme effort to parse input after all, otherwise there is little merit in having it in WordPress.

Comment: It only needed to be displayed inline. I am will use a text replacing widget to make adding this format user friendly..